# ionic 4 change the size and color of a button issues

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, scss-mixins

I use the following code to allow me change the color of button when I click the button. It works fine. But when I try to add CSS to change the width and height of the buttons. The color change were working but the button size didn't change. Here is my code :

```
html code 
<ion-content padding>
   <ion-row>
       <ion-col width-50 style="text-align: right" no-padding >
    <button ion-button full no-margin class="bsize" (click)="addEvent('b1');" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': buttonColorb1}">button 1</button>
</ion-col>
 <ion-col width-50 style="text-align: left" no-padding>
    <button ion-button full no-margin class="bsize" (click)="addEvent('b2');" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': buttonColorb2}">button 2</button>
  </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

</ion-content>

scss code :

.bsize {
   --width: 100px;
   --height: 40px;
}

ts code :

export class TestButtonPage implements OnInit {
buttonColorb1: string = '#D3D3D3'; //Default Color
buttonColorb2: string  = '#D3D3D3'; //Default Color
constructor() { }

addEvent(btn){
if (btn == "b1") {
   this.buttonColorb1 = '#add8e6'; //desired Color
   this.buttonColorb2  = '#D3D3D3'; //desired Color
}
else {
   this.buttonColorb1   = '#add8e6'; //desired Color
   this.buttonColorb2  = '#D3D3D3'; //desired Color
  }
}
ngOnInit() {
   this.buttonColorb1 = '#add8e6'; //desired Color
   this.buttonColorb2  = '#D3D3D3'; //desired Color
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use below CSS,**

```
.bsize {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-1msy43?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.scss)